# PDOStatement returns a string: Is this a PHP Bug?

Tags: php, pdo, sqlite

I am considering filing a PHP bug report. My question is: Is this a PHP bug?

I am looking for a "yes"/"no" answers to help me decide if I should file the bug report.

The problem is that the PDOStatement::fetch(PDO:FETCH_NUM) for SQLite in PHP7 returns a string when it should return an array.

In 2008, PHP rejected a similar report for the MySQL Driver on bug report #44341

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44341

In report #44341, PHP programmers said that this is not a PHP bug, but a problem with the MySQL driver. MySQL fixed the problem.

Here is my argument that this is a PHP Bug.

SQLite is a public domain, standards based, "zero configuration" database that developers can embed in their product.

**SQLite does not have drivers**. SQLite is, by definition, an embedded database.

PDO_SQLITE is a product created by PHP which "embeds" SQLite as a driver. See the PHP manual php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-sqlite.php

Digging deeper. It appears that the reason PDOStatement::fetch() returns a string instead of an array is that SQLite is a standards based program. The SQL standard outputs data as a string.

The MySQL driver hands PHP an array which PDO passes through to the user.

The reason that PDO fails is because the SQLite Driver delivers a string according to SQL Standards. PHP's PDO product appears to be optimized for non-standard output coming from the MySQL driver.

I consider the problems that I have to be a PHP Bug for several reasons:

1) SQLite is an embedded database. It does not have drivers. It is up to the company embedding SQLite to make SQLite work.

2) PHP advertises a product called PDO_SQLITE. This product implies that has accepted that they they have taken the responsibility of making SQLite work with their product.

(SQLite is not a client/server database. It is an embedded database making it a completely different thing.)

3) The SQLite output is based on SQL standards. The bug report #44341 tells me that PDO is dependent on the output from a proprietary third party driver.

My question for StackOverflow is: Is this a PHP bug, or am I off my rocker?

BTW, the bug I want to report is not simply that SQLite implementation of PDOStatement::fetch() returns a string.

The bug I want to report is that PHP appears to have a dependency on the MySQL Driver, MySQL is now a wholly owned division of ORACLE, and I want to avoid dependencies on ORACLE.

My question for StackOverflow is: Does my argument make sense?

If I issue the bug report, I need to have a clear argument as to why the reason PHP rejected report #44341 about MySQL does not apply to SQLite.

The following link shows the error.

http://yintercept.com/resources/new.php

Answer (score 0):

I decided to file the Bug Report although I suspect an instant dismissal. A dependency on a proprietary driver is a bug in the open source world.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=71185